# Summing Weekly Meeting Packages Revenue

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm selling my services in a package of 10 meetings with different prices per client.
I need a way to calculate my weekly revenue over the year.
The current formula is very messy and creates problems when moving clients around the sheet:

> "=count(C2)*$B$2+count(C3:C6)*$B$3+count(C7:C9)*$B$7+count(C10)*$B$10"

I wish I could use SUMPRODUCT but since the meetings are numbered it ruins the calculations.
Do you have an easier way to execute this?

Simplified Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LA_y7CBipVIstQfyVqqRTd2pkSQzRiPsjwZQYyvHuTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$B10,--(C2:C10>0))
```

- (C2:C10>0) is an array of TRUE and FALSE values of whether there is a meeting for that client.
- “--“ of that is the trick that converts a TRUE/FALSE array into a binary arrays of 1s and 0s suitable for sumproduct.

Then fill across.